# SQL Server: Query Efficiency Having vs Subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query where I used a sub query since I can't use aggregates in the where clause.

`SSMS` suggested I use the `HAVING` clause but then I would need to group by all the other columns (right?) which I did not want to have to do so I ended up using the sub query.

Is using the sub query the most efficient way or should I use the Having clause so I don't have to read from the same table twice?

Is the difference negligible?

```
select *
from [DW_STAGE].[ETL].[Claims]
where pd_dt > (
        select dateadd(m, - 12, cast(max(pd_dt) as date))
        from [DW_STAGE].[ETL].[Claims]
        )
```

Comment: How did SSMS suggest this syntax? Are you using the horrible query designer?

Comment: If you want a better answer, please provide the table schema (or *at least* the indexes) and perhaps some sample data. I'm also worried that `pd_dt` is not a date/datetime/datetime2 column, and that this might bloat an index, but again, I'm just guessing here for lack of a table schema.

Comment: @DanielHutmacher: I don't think there is any evidence that `pd_dt` is not a `datetime` or `datetime2`. The OP may be casting it to `date` simply to cover whole days.

Answer (score 3):

If your table's clustered index has `pd_dt` as the first column, this may be the most optimal query. You could simplify it by breaking it into two parts, like so:

```
DECLARE @dt date;
SELECT @dt=DATEADD(month, -12, CAST(MAX(pd_dt) AS date)) FROM DW_STAGE.ETL.Claims;

SELECT * FROM DW_STAGE.ETL.Claims WHERE pd_dt>@dt;
```

Things you could do to improve performance:

- Reduce the number of columns from `*` to those specific columns that you need.
- Create a covering, non-clustered index for these columns, where the first column of the index is `pd_dt` or `pd_dt DESC`.

Comment: I think it would be a covering index even if `pd_dt` was the only key column, al the others being in INCLUDE.

Comment: Exactly, `INCLUDE` being what makes the index covering (unless it's already clustered).

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see how using HAVING would let you avoid reading from the same table twice. The only way I can see HAVING could be used here is in combination with a self-join – more specifically, self-cross join. That already sounds... not very promising. And yes, you are right, you would need to put all the output columns (which in your case would be all `DW_STAGE.ETL.Claims` columns) in the GROUP BY. It would probably look along the lines of this:

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  DW_STAGE.ETL.Claims AS t1
  CROSS JOIN
  DW_STAGE.ETL.Claims AS t2
GROUP BY
  t1.column1,
  t1.column2,
  ... /* and so on to include all t1 columns */
HAVING
  t1.pd_st > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CAST(max(pd_dt) AS date));
```

Obviously, the table is touched twice here – just as in your posted query, except this query is much uglier than yours.

Nevertheless, it is possible to accomplish what you want without referencing the table twice. You can use window aggregation and a derived table for that:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      max_pd_dt = MAX(pd_dt) OVER ()
    FROM
      DW_STAGE.ETL.Claims
  ) AS s
WHERE
  pd_dt > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CAST(max_pd_dt AS date))
;
```

Or your can substitute a CTE for the derived table:

```
WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      max_pd_dt = MAX(pd_dt) OVER ()
    FROM
      DW_STAGE.ETL.Claims
  ) AS s
SELECT
  *
FROM
  cte
WHERE
  pd_dt > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CAST(max_pd_dt AS date))
;
```

Note that the `*` in the outer query includes the `max_pd_dt` column returned by the nested SELECT. To exclude it from the output, you will have to explicitly specify only the `DW_STAGE.ETL.Claims` columns. That would actually be a good time to heed [Daniel Hutmacher's advice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127041/6965) to limit your output to just the columns you really need. (And I agree with his other suggestion of creating a covering index.)